# Deprecated Apis when compiling

Tags: flutter, package, deprecated

```
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.6.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-2.5.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-2.5.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\streamhandler\TransactionStreamHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.                      
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-3.1.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-10.0.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:38: warning: [deprecation] Registrar in PluginRegistry has been deprecated
  public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry.Registrar registrar) {
                                                ^
1 warning                                                               
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.                
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geocoding-2.0.1\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geocoding\GeocodingPlugin.java uses 
or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.8.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

I faced this warning notes when compiling, it doesn't give a problem but i want to delete that.
I tried to update the packages to the last versions, but still gives the warnings.
I think i should delete a pub cache file or something like that.
Help please!

Comment: I'm afraid you can't really do anything. These packages need to be updated, until then you will see these warnings. But these are warnings, not errors.

Comment: Okey, thank you for you asnwer.